# Windows 8 Shutdown delayed

Tags: windows-8.1, shutdown

I have a windows 8 laptop and just got this problem starting a week ago. The issue happen after my laptop battery is exhausted ( my parent unplug the charger ). Soon after that, every shutdown did not show the normal shutdown screen, it just stay on the desktop like nothing happened. I tried the command `shutdown -s -t 0 -f` , a command prompt box appear then gone, but still stay on desktop view. A few minutes later ( roughly 5 to 10 minutes ) my laptop finally off.

I have tried a clean boot, disabling some service and even Refresh using my custom image, the problem still persist.

Is there anything that I missed or any other solution before I try to completely reinstall the OS?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have enabled this option

> Shutdown: Clear virtual memory pagefile

[Microsoft article](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/320423)

[Related info](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-group-policy-pagefile.htm)

Comment: it is disabled. so, it is not about clear pagefile right?